# How to fix a part of a washed out asphalt driveway?

Tags: driveway, asphalt

This is what a washed out part looks like:

[image]

and (same spot, from the front):

[image]

from looking at fixing potholes online, it seems like filling it with a [paver base](https://www.homedepot.com/p/0-5-cu-ft-Gray-Paver-Base-98001/100580973) and topping it with a couple inches of [backtop repair](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Quikrete-50-lb-Commercial-Grade-Blacktop-Repair-170152/100545936) might work, but I am not sure whether those work for the area this large.

What would be a recommended way of fixing this? I understand that repaving the whole driveway would fix it, but I'd like to see whether spending 35 times less and fixing it myself is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't look "washed out", as in storm damage. It looks disintegrated due to age or an inadequate base. The only right fix is excavation, installation of a suitable base, and reapplication of asphalt. Anything short of that will come apart again fairly quickly.

You wouldn't necessarily need to replace the entire driveway if this is the only troublesome area, but it looks to me like it was laid on soil that's at least partially organic.

Comment: thanks. does it mean there is nothing I can really do, but to excavate it (make the area even bigger) and then apply "paver base" and "backtop repair"?