# Why is newly applied asphalt not smooth?

Tags: driveway, asphalt, paving

I finally decided to hire professionals to [fix my driveway](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/136177/how-to-fix-a-part-of-a-washed-out-asphalt-driveway) rather than trying to excavate it myself.

This is a newly repaved piece of the driveway:

[image]

I would expect it to be smooth and even, am I missing something? This is after the finished layer was applied, but it looks and feels somewhat rocky.

Should a newly repaved asphalt driveway (done right) look like that?

Comment: that looks just fine

Comment: @jsotola What makes you think it’s “just fine”?

Comment: THis looks like the price of oil went up for asphalt and they used just enough to get it wet requiring you to seal it.

Comment: it looks like the parking lot at my apartment building and i have not seen any problems with it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is terrible and totally unacceptable.

There are several issues: 1) insufficient asphalt to bind the aggregates, 2) no compaction, 3) improper aggregate mix,

1) Asphalt (liquid) should be a thick soupy consistency that completely coats the aggregates throughout the top 2” minimum layer.

2) With loose rocks laying on the top, this is an indication that it was not compacted. Rocks should not be able to be kicked off your driveway.

3) The aggregate mix is very specific for good performance. There needs to be a certain amount of fines (sand), 1/4” minus (small crushed rocks), and 3/4” minus crushed rocks. This is important so that the rocks “bind” together when compacted. (There should NOT be any smooth edged rocks anywhere in the mix. Smooth rocks are not crushed rocks and will not bind together with other rocks.)

I’d dig up a couple of random spots and check the depth of the asphalt and the base. The minimum asphalt depth is 2” and minimum base is 4”...good practices require a minimum of 8” base.

I’d also notify the local Building Official and the local Construction Contractor’s Board (CCB).  Get their CCB license number and file a complaint. (They can help to resolve the issue.) I’d also contact a local civil engineer to review the project.

It’s the worst I’ve ever seen.

Comment: Yes that is sad ,  Looks like first coat water going to seep in and frost heave .

Comment: That stuff happens up north .They are called Gypsy hot toppers.Show up when asphalt plant starts put down a binder get the money and leave. The real pro in my area wont even put asphalt down if he does not due the site work himself.

Answer (score 0):

That does not look like asphalt pavement ( aka - bituminous concrete). It looks like what I call "chip and seal", basically gravel is spread and sprayed with a tar or asphalt liquid. Did they roll your drive with heavy equipment , not tamp it down ? It is satisfactory for lightly used roadways,parking lots and driveways. I lived in a small rural subdivision where it was used for the streets; it was OK except each spot the garbage collection truck stopped ,a pot hole developed.